# What does a red flag next to a weapon mean?

Tags: splatoon-3

On the weapon select screen, I noticed there was a red flag next to my Splattershot. All of my other weapons had a gray flag. What does the red flag next to my Splattershot mean?

[image: Splattershot with red flag]

Answer (score 1):

That's a mechaninc also present in Splatoon 2, and as [confirmed on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/splatoon/comments/xcmv5d/splatoon_3_faq_answers_to_commonly_asked/) and the official wikia too, it's the **Turf War freshness**:

[image]

(Not to be confused with Weapon freshness!)

[image]
<sub>Indicated by stars</sub>

Each rating has a specific flag color that is displayed beside a weapon's name in the weapon select. The flag's color is representative of that weapon's highest Freshness rating, not its current rating.

Turf War freshness (flag) is shown in an icon on the right when selecting Turf War from the lobby menu. It correlates to how many matches you've won or lost with your equipped weapon. Winning will increase the bar, and losing will decrease it. As the meter increases, your weapon will be marked with a little colored flag next to its name in your equipment screen, corresponding to how much Turf War freshness you've attained with it.

This is how [Freshness](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Freshness) chart works:

| **Title** | **Score to Reach** | **Score Penalty on Loss** | **Flag Color** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | 0 | -0.5 | Grey |
| [image] | 5 | -1 | Green |
| [image] | 10 | -1.5 | Orange |
| [image] | 15 | -2 | Silver |
| [image] | 50 | -3 | Gold |

Comment: How do the weapon stars correlate with the flag color next to the weapon?

Comment: They don't, I left that part since both are named "freshness" which is ambiguous, specifying that the one your are asking is the Turf War Freshness.

Comment: Bonuses are only given in Splatoon 2; the flag is purely cosmetic in 3.

Comment: @wutadam yeah true, I experienced the same, forgot to remove that. Thanks.